# Crystal Reports Subreport only showing last record

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a main report that returns several rows and then i'm trying to get a sub report to generate based on the values in each row of the main report.  Right now the sub report is only working when the values are in the last row or all the same.  Here is an example of the main report:

```
Product   Po#   Price
apples    3     5
grapes    2     7
oranges   5     6
```

My subreport should show all the data on po#s 1, 2 & 5.  But as of right now it is only showing the data on po# 5.  I am thinking I need to store those PO#s in an array and then link that array to the subreport??  Does that sound right?  How would I do that?  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: How have you linked the main to the sub-report?

Comment: Yes they are linked via po number.

Comment: what section of the report are you placing the subreport in? (details, group, footer,etc.)

Comment: Footer.  It would work in the details section, but then it would be displayed between each line.  That is not what I want.  I want the first table then the second.

Comment: @BenGeisinger well that's your problem then, if it's in the footer then the main report is only sending the last POnumber as the link to the subreport, you are going to have to move this to the detail section, or like you said create an array and use that as the parameter for the sub report.

Comment: That is what i'm having trouble with.  How would you create this array?  Would you do a whileprinting?

Comment: An easier option is to just duplicate the logic on the main report in the subreport so that you get all the same records; you'll avoid having to create the array and then pass it into the sub as a parameter.

Comment: In what way do you wish to generate results in your subreport? can you show us the formula or command?